# JavaScript - Uncaught ReferenceError: KEY is not defined

Tags: syntax-error

I'm reading a book on creating games with HTML5 and have problem with this code.no matter what i do i can't make it work.i removed descriptions from code so it's less to read.and all the code here is copied from book.

I get the error  " Uncaught ReferenceError: KEY is not defined " for UP KEY on line 23.and if i remove that block of code entirely i get the same error for DOWN KEY so what do you think is the problem?

```
var pingpong = {}
pingpong.pressedKeys = [];
$(function(){

pingpong.timer = setInterval(gameloop,30);

$(document).keydown(function(e){
pingpong.pressedKeys[e.which] = true;
});
$(document).keyup(function(e){
pingpong.pressedKeys[e.which] = false;
});
});



function gameloop() {
movePaddles();
}
function movePaddles() {

pressed.
if (pingpong.pressedKeys[KEY.UP]) {

var top = parseInt($("#paddleB").css("top"));
$("#paddleB").css("top",top-5);
}
if (pingpong.pressedKeys[KEY.DOWN]) { 

var top = parseInt($("#paddleB").css("top"));
$("#paddleB").css("top",top+5);
}


if (pingpong.pressedKeys[KEY.W]) { 

var top = parseInt($("#paddleA").css("top"));
$("#paddleA").css("top",top-5);
}
if (pingpong.pressedKeys[KEY.S]) { 

var top = parseInt($("#paddleA").css("top"));
$("#paddleA").css("top",top+5);
}
}
```

Comment: The `pressed.` just after `function movePaddles() {` looks suspicious

Comment: I had similar issue and all was needed it to write Object.keys(....) instead of just keys(),  I was looking for the keys of json object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`KEY` should be defined somewhere in your tutorial

Probably like this:

```
KEY = {
    UP: 38,
    DOWN: 40,
    ...
}
```

Comment: God bless you.found the code.it's barely mentioned and it's not part of steps.

Comment: It's probably used in every game where the keyboard is involved